# jQuery .toggleClass works on second click, NOT on first click

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a button that toggles background images between a bird in a cage and a birdless cage representing a boolean option with the following images:

Boolean: Text is published   = Image: cage with no bird.
Boolean: Text is unpublished = Image: cage with no bird.

If the page loads and the bird cage is empty (the text is published), I can click it and it toggles the way it is supposed to: the bird is back in the cage. But if I load the page and the text is not published, when I click on the bird in the cage the appropriate data is sent, but the image does not toggle (the bird is still in the cage despite being published). And when I click it again, the toggle starts working, but is now out of sync with the boolean state.

This is a Rails app. Here is my code:
jQuery:

```
$("#text_publish<%= @text.id %>").toggleClass(function() {
  if ($(this).is('.birdCagePublished')) {
    return 'birdCageUnPublished';
  } else {
    return 'birdCagePublished';
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.birdCagePublished {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(emptyCage.png);
}

.birdCageUnPublished {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;  
  background-image: url(fullCage.png);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<a alt="Begin Freewriting" class="birdCageUnPublished" data-remote="true" href="/text/3400/toggle_published" id="text_publish3400"></a>
</div.
```

Text Controller Toggle Method:

```
  def toggle_published
    @text = Text.find(params[:id])
    @text.toggle!(:published)
  end
```

Log on successful toggle:

```
Started GET "/text/3400/toggle_published" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-01 00:07:29 -0500
Processing by TextController#toggle_published as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3400"}
  [1m[35mText Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "text".* FROM "text" WHERE "text"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "3400"]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  UPDATE "text" SET "published" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "text"."id" = 3400  [["published", false], ["updated_at", Sat, 01 Nov 2014 05:07:29 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (0.8ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  Rendered text/toggle_published.js.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 2.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

Started GET "/assets/fullCage.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-01 00:07:29 -0500
```

Log for failed toggle:

```
Started GET "/text/3400/toggle_published" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-01 00:09:32 -0500
Processing by TextController#toggle_published as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3400"}
  [1m[36mText Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "text".* FROM "text" WHERE "text"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "3400"]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "text" SET "published" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "text"."id" = 3400[0m  [["published", true], ["updated_at", Sat, 01 Nov 2014 05:09:32 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  COMMIT
  Rendered text/toggle_published.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 3.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Notice the log on the unsuccessful toggle does not GET "/assets/emptyCage.png"What do you think?

Comment: Is it just me or are your css declarations backwards? You have Published mapping to fullCage and vice versa, the opposite of what you described..

Comment: Where is the actual toggle class function getting called or have you forgotten to include that?

Comment: tried adding a .toggleClass() after the toggleClass(function(){..}) in jquery. although am not not sure.

Comment: are you sure that the class is set correctly after page load in case the text is not published?